# Windows 10 keeps disconnecting from one specific wifi network and is not able to find it in available networks again

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I have an Asus X456U Laptop with a Qualcomm Atheros AR956x wifi network adapter. On Windows 10 I'm not able to connect to my home wifi network with a message can't connect to this network. After this, the network would disappear from the list of available networks until I disable/enable my wifi adapter from settings.
Sometimes it connects to the network and works for like 10 minutes then disconnects automatically and again the network would not show up on the list until I disable/enable from adapter options in windows settings.

- I have an Ubuntu 16.04 on the same laptop which works without a problem with the same network.
- Other devices (android phones) connect to the same network and work without a problem.
- I tried uninstalling the driver completely and installed two different versions of the driver for Atheros (version 10 and 11) but the problem is still there.
- I disabled IPV6. It didn't help.
- Everything was working fine until 3 days ago and nothing is changed as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe the wireless adapter is not compatible with different age routers. Ubuntu V16 is, itself, an older OS. Try a USB Wireless Adapter and see if that works with your router. Also update the firmware in your router.

Comment: This setup was working 3 days ago and suddenly it just stopped working. I didn't change the router or the operating system at this time. I also check with an Ubuntu 18.04 live disk now and it also works.

Comment: I have had issues with Atheros adapter before and changed them out for Intel adapters with much better success.

Comment: You mean physically change it or just the driver?

Comment: I meant try an external Wireless adapter to see if it gives you better results overall.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with the wireless network adapter. It seems challenging to resolve, but you have options. Consider purchasing a new internal PCIe network adapter. Alternatively, you can opt for an external USB adapter, which will function well, albeit using one of your laptop's USB ports. i use toshiba satellite c50 a .